# Delphi Reverse Decrypt Function

Tags: delphi

I have the following code in delphi to decrypt:

```
      new_size := Length(Source) - 1;
      for c := 24 to new_size - 1 do
        begin
          v := Source[c];
          v := v - key;
          v := v AND $FF;
          x := v XOR (Source[c + 1]);
          Source[c] := x;
        end;
```

where

```
      Source: Array of Byte;

      Key: Byte;
```

Any one a quick idea how to reverse this (encrypt again) ?

Comment: v is byte type too, so i think in this version the AND $FF is obsolete...

Comment: Yes, if v is byte, then and $FF is pointless

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code is the inverse of the code in the question:

```
for c := new_size - 1 downto 24 do
  Source[c] := (Source[c] xor Source[c+1]) + key;
```

And the code in the question can be written much more simply like this:

```
for c := 24 to new_size - 1 do
  Source[c] := (Source[c] - key) xor Source[c+1];
```